Calling Vertex AI Endpoint for Swift (IOS application)
I have created a tuned model in Vertex AI and deployed it into an endpoint. I would like to use the tuned model in my Swift IOS application, but I don't know how.
Are there any ways to call it using Swift code? Or are there other ways?
I tried to search all documentations, but I don't know what to do after deployment of endpoint.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can use the REST method to send request to your finetuned model deployed on vertexai.
you may use something like this to send request using Swift
import Foundation

// Replace these placeholders with your actual values
let tuningJobRegion = "YOUR_TUNING_JOB_REGION"
let projectId = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
let endpointId = "YOUR_ENDPOINT_ID"
let urlString = "https://\(tuningJobRegion)-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/\(projectId)/locations/\(tuningJobRegion)/endpoints/\(endpointId):generateContent"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    print("Invalid URL")
    return
}

// Create a URL request and specify the HTTP method as POST
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// Define the JSON body
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "contents": [
        [
            "role": "USER",
            "parts": [
                "text": "Why is the sky blue?"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "generation_config": [
        "temperature": 0.7,    // Replace with your value for TEMPERATURE
        "topP": 0.9,           // Replace with your value for TOP_P
        "topK": 50,            // Replace with your value for TOP_K
        "maxOutputTokens": 100 // Replace with your value for MAX_OUTPUT_TOKENS
    ]
]

do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
} catch {
    print("Failed to serialize JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
}

// Set the necessary HTTP headers
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let session = URLSession.shared

// Create a data task to send the data to the API
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    
    // Ensure that we have data
    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data returned")
        return
    }
    
    // Try to decode the data into a usable format (e.g., JSON)
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            print("JSON response: \(json)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to decode JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

task.resume()

you can find REST methods for every thing in documentation
like this
